# Cycling values in a hidden field on image click

Tags: jquery, html, hidden-field

I hope someone can help me. I am new to jquery. I want to show pictures of my students on a page so I can take the presence easily. I made that using a MySQL DB with php. That's the easy part.

Next, i managed to make a jquery script so when I click each image the border of that image cycle through green, red and yellow (in - out - late css class).

Here is the html code (id from hidden field is the student number)

```
<div class="presences-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="presences-image in"><img src="7465.jpg">
        <input type="hidden" id="7465" name="presence2" value="in"/></li>
        <li class="presences-image out"><img src="9484.jpg">
        <input type="hidden" id="9484" name="presence3" value="in"/></li>
        <li class="presences-image late"><img src="2627.jpg">
        <input type="hidden" id="2627" name="presence4" value="in"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('li').toggle(
 function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('in out');
 $(this).removeClass('in');
 ;}, 
 function() {

 $(this).toggleClass('out late');
 $(this).removeClass('out');
 },
 function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('late in');
 $(this).removeClass('late');
 }
 );

});
```

Now, I want to set each hidden field value according to the state of the image (in ou or late) with jquery and submit all hidden field to put it in my DB.

Hope I'm clear enough!

Thanks in advance for your help!!

François

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

just change the type to **hidden**.

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6WNK/40/)

**html:**

```
<div class="presences-container">
<ul id="ulPics">
    <li class="presences-image in"><img src="7465.jpg">
    <input type="text" id="7465" name="presence2"/></li>
    <li class="presences-image out"><img src="9484.jpg">
    <input type="text" id="9484" name="presence3"/></li>
    <li class="presences-image late"><img src="2627.jpg">
    <input type="text" id="2627" name="presence4"/></li>
</ul>
```

**js:**

```
$("#ulPics li input").each(function(){
      $(this).val($(this).parents('li').attr("class").split(" ")[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some code like this to update the corresponding `hidden` fields when the the `<li>`s have been clicked -

```
var hiddenid = $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace(".jpg",""); 
$("#" + hiddenid).val($(this).attr('class').split(' ').splice(-1));
```

You could then serialize your hidden input values like this -

```
vat hiddenvals = $("input[type=hidden]").serialize();
```

And then post back to you your server using the '[post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post)' or '[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)' methods.

Comment: Thanks! I have to serialize values in a submit action? I have to add a jQuery function to the submit button?

Comment: Everything is fine! :) I found the form.submit function :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, something like this should do the trick:

```
var states = $(['late','out','in']);

$('li').click(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        $hiddenField = $this.find('input:hidden'),
        idx = $.inArray($hiddenField.val(), states);

    // update hidden field
    $hiddenField.val(states.get(--idx));

    // update li
    $this.removeClass('in out late').addClass($hiddenField.val());

});
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDaea/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, but when value get to late, how do I get it back to in if I click again? I mean that it does not go back to initial state on 3rd click... :/

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

var states = $(['late','out','in']);

$('li').click(function() {
 
    var $this = $(this),
        $hiddenField = $this.find('input:hidden'),
  idx = $.inArray($hiddenField.val(), states);

  if(idx == 0) {
   idx = 3;
  }

 // update hidden field
    $hiddenField.val(states.get(--idx));

    // update li
    $this.removeClass('in out late').addClass($hiddenField.val());
 
 alert(idx);

});

});

Comment: When you go to 'late', it should __automatically__ cycle back to 'in' on the next iteration. The reason why we're using a jQuery-wrapped array (instead of just a plain array) is that `$().get()` allows you to pass in a __negative index__, which effectively goes through the array in reverse (you can't do that with something like `array[-1]`). When your index is 0, the next iteration will get you an index of -1, which should give you 'in'. No code change necessary.